# Check for changes to class attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

There is a React function that returns a list of card elements.

[image]

When we click one of the elements, the class attribute value becomes `card expanded`.

What can we do in JavaScript or jQuery to detect a change in one of these class attributes? When a change is detected on click, I want to check if the element is within viewport, and if so, scroll the element into view.

Any idea how to do the first part?

Comment: `$(document).on('click','.card',function(){ if($(this).hasClass('expanded')){//do some stuff}});`

Comment: Looks good, you want to create an answer from that?

Comment: You can use a mutation observer to check when a class is changed by an external script on a given element.

Comment: Sorry i am late. But i hope you got the answer or idea how to do that

Comment: @AlivetoDie OP wants to detect the class change, not a click event

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  OP says that:-`When we click one of the elements, the class attribute value becomes card expanded` . So i think that on click of div this class is added to the clicked div. That's why i gave that code